# How to embed a report with pre-configured visual level filters?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

We are embedding a report in SharePoint, we cascade the filters from dropdown to the embedded report's individual visual slicers. The cascading happens after the report loads with the default-saved filter combination (it results in queries getting fired twice at the backend AAS server). Is there a way to only load the report with default visual level filters.

We are aware that report level filter config at loaded event is possible.

Comment: We can have the embedded report loaded directly via pre-configured slicers, Microsoft documentation provides the following references: 1. [Control Report slicers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-slicers#setting-slicers-on-report-load) 2. [On load Slicers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#on-load-slicers)